# Add possibility to draw rectangles and ovals by two mouse clicks

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a possibility to draw rectangles and ovals by two mouse clicks.

I want to draw a rectangle every time user clicks on the "Rectangle" and "ovals" button and then clicks on the JFrame based on the event x and y coordinates. 
I need a component class the draws the rectangle and I have another class that has JFrame mouse press listener.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Painter extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener, ChangeListener {

    private JButton clearButton; //Pole danych do przechowywania przycisku czyszczacego
    private JPanel menu;
    private JPanel workspace;

    private JSlider suwak;
    int size;
    private JButton klik;
    private Color kolor;



    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public Painter(int sz, int w) {
        //Stworzenie interfejsu graficznego (GUI)
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //Ustawienie sposobu ukladania komponentow
        menu = new JPanel(); //Stworzenie panelu menu
        menu.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Ustawienie layout dla tego panelu
        menu.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); //Ustawienie koloru tła
        clearButton = new JButton("Clear"); //Stworzenie nowego przycisku
        menu.add(clearButton); // Dodanie przycisku do panelu menu
        this.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Dodanie menu na górze okna
        workspace = new JPanel(); //Stworzenie panelu pola do rysowania
        // dodanie obsługi zdarzeń kliknięcia i ruchu po panelu
        workspace.addMouseListener(this);
        workspace.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        this.add(workspace, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Dodanie pola do rysowania w środku okna
        this.setSize(sz,w); // Ustawienie wymiarów okna
        this.setTitle("Painter"); // Nazwa okna
        clearButton.addActionListener(this); //Aktywowanie obslugi przycisku


        suwak = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 5, 25, 10);
        suwak.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        suwak.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        suwak.setPaintTicks(true);
        suwak.setPaintLabels(true);
        suwak.addChangeListener(this);
        menu.add(suwak);
        size=10;

        klik = new JButton("Set Color");
        klik.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(klik);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    // wywołanie metody paint klasy JFrame
    super.paint(g);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource() == clearButton) //Sprawdzenie czy zrodlem zdarzenia jest przycisk
    {
    //Czyszczenie pola roboczego
    workspace.getGraphics().clearRect(0, 0, workspace.getWidth(), workspace.getHeight());

    } 
    if(e.getSource() == klik) //Sprawdzenie czy zrodlem zdarzenia jest przycisk
    {

    kolor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,  "Choose a color", kolor);

    }
    }
    //Rysowanie w momencie przeciagania myszy (przycisniety przycisk + mysz w ruchu)
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = workspace.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(kolor);
    g.fillOval(e.getX()-5, e.getY()-(size/2), size, size);
    e.consume();
    }
    //Rysowanie w momencie przycisniecia przycisku myszy
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics g = workspace.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(kolor);
    g.fillOval(e.getX()-5, e.getY()-(size/2), size, size);
    e.consume();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Painter paint = new Painter(500,500); //Ustawienia rozmiarów okna
    //Ustalenie operacji po kliknięciu na X
    paint.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    paint.setVisible(true); // Ustawienie widoczności okna


    }


    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
    if(e.getSource() == suwak) //Sprawdzenie czy zrodlem zdarzenia jest przycisk
    {


        size = suwak.getValue();
    } 
    }


}
```

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a couple of examples on how to draw Rectangles by dragging the mouse.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) Code comments in English are useful to the majority of people reading here, OTOH code comments in any other language are useless to most - noise. Please either translate or remove them.